# filter manytoone relationship, exclude childs on condition

Tags: python, django

I have a one to many relationship with category and products, category and product have active fields, if any of them are not active I want to exclude them from list.

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

But now category can have many products, and some of them are inactive, how could I filter and exclude inactive products from all of categories?

Models:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)   

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to filter related pruducts you can use [`prefetc_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with `Prefetch` object:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
categories = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related(Prefetch('product_set', queryset=Produc.objects.filter(is_active=True)))
```

in this case for each category from `categories` this code

```
category.product_set.all()
```

will return only active product. Moreover this queryset will not hit DB, since related product will be cached by first query.